# Error trying to send email using spring cloud aws (SES)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I'm trying to send emails using spring-cloud-aws. Bellow the relevant snippets:

application.properties:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
```

MailSendingService:

```
@Service
public class MailSendingService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void sendMailMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("noreply@xxx.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo("johndoe@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("test subject");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("test content");
        this.mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    MailSendingService mailService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init() {
        return (evt) -> {
            mailService.sendMailMessage();
        };
    }
}
```

In my POM I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed
>   messages: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The request signature
>   we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your
>   AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service
>   documentation for details.
>
> The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST /
>
> amz-sdk-invocation-id:3a35628a-ca4d-5d3f-666a-1bd596b25a0
>   amz-sdk-retry:3/230/485 host:email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
>   user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.18 Windows_10/10.0
>   Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.92-b14/1.8.0_92
>   x-amz-date:20170201T113844Z
>
> amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date
>   c87e0a9aed59cebfbf123b9a248c1bece98e17c59ab38486fef0220d1f86da'
>
> The String-to-Sign should have been 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20170201T113844Z
>   20170201/us-east-1/ses/aws4_request
>   daa69ea00e5c19ce5123fdbfe0c335d2678516925dc2042f7627d9660520ef'
>   (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID:
>   fd73a86-e872-11e6-a68d-7b50079b6d0)

I have triple checked the keys. Any ideas?

Comment: Were u able to resolve this issue?